# How can I make my clients (host) use my Squid proxy inside Docker container?

Tags: linux, proxy, docker, squid

I'm new in Squid and Docker.

Example, I have 1 client (IP: 192.168.0.200) and 1 host (IP: 192.168.0.15). If client want to connect to the internet, then in host will be created container which contains squid proxy (*I pull form the sameersbn/squid:latest`)*

And my syntax to create the container is:

```
docker run -d -net None --name SQUID_192.168.0.200 -p 9001:3128 -v /home/administrator/container-data:/var/log/squid3
```

And configuration IP in my client like this:

> auto enp0s3
> iface enp0s3 inet static
> address 192.168.0.200
> netmask 255.255.255.0
> gateway 192.168.0.15

Then I use iptables to forward packet from 192.168.0.200 to the container

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i wlp3s0 -s 192.168.0.200 --dport 9001
```

**Here's my problem:**

1. I don't know better use `-net None` or `-net Host` or something else
2. I do not know if my way is right or not, to direct the packet form 192.168.0.200 to container name SQUID_192.168.0.200 *(I'm tried using port 9001:3128)*
3. I have tried to access internet from the client, I opened `google.com` and `detik.com`, but it's not recorded in access.log